# BIRT : Generate a Dynamic Hyperlink from XML Data

Tags: javascript, birt

I have an XML dataset with values in the following format:

```
        name        value         
    ----------|----------------|
       ip     | 192.168.1.17   |
       port   | 8080           |
       suburl | report1        |
```

Now I have to put an generate an hyperlink, with a combination of the data.

```
    For example: http://192.168.1.17:8080/birt/run?__report=test.rptdesign
```

I have tried something along the following lines:

1. Created a table of the XML dataset. Made it invisible.
2. Created the following script on the table onCreate

   ```
   var index;
   myArray = new Array(10);
   for(index=0; index < myArray.length; index++) {
   myArray[index]=row['value'];
   }
   ```
3. I'm using "http://"+myArray[0]+":"+myArray[1] in the hyperlink

   ```
   But I'm getting the following result: http://192.168.1.17:192.168.1.17
   ```

I think all the array elements seems to contain the first row of the table only.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you described it is obvious:

You are looping 10 times which is the length of `myArray` array, filling all fields of array with `row['value']` value which at the time you are running loop has value `192.168.1.17`.

I don't see why do you need to dynamically fill URL values that way, I'm sure there are easier ways.

Comment: I have to integrate birt reports to our appication which is running on jboss. So the html reports are being embedded into our pages as: http://serverip:jboss-port/birt/run?__report=report1.rptdesign The server ip and jboss port number might change according to the production environment. Is there any other way as you mentioned ?

Comment: I'm picking up the jboss url from a properties file

Comment: If I understand correctly, onCreate method (script event) for table is report script event for table as report display element? Once you are in a report, there is no point to generate report URL -> you are already in it. You need to manage it before invoking script in your application

Comment: OK. The Report here is a summary, kind of a dashboard of reports. There are many hyperlinks, which lead them to individual reports as pop ups. I'm using uris, because drill throughs are not working for me

Comment: OK, but don't structure your dataset like name/value but like sourceX/server/port/report_name and you'll avoid the problem you have (store all data within the same row). If you want to stick with the dataset for configuring your reports access...

Comment: Thanks Miki, I had thought about this solution before posting this question. But for the sake of knowing things in depth, I have posted this. Suppose, we have an xml dataset and we need to use a particular cell's value. Anyway, Thanks for the answer.

Comment: NP, you can always upvote it or accept it if you find it usefull.